# How do I filter by time in a date time field?

Tags: python, django

In the model 'entered' is a datetime field. I want to query the data to find all entry's that where made between noon(start_time) and 5:00pm (end_time).

```
selected = Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte=start_time, entered__lte=end_time)
```

(as I expected)I get an error of:

```
"ValidationError: Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format."
```

So I know I can use __year so I tried.

```
selected = Entry.objects.filter(entered__time__gte=start_time, entered__time__lte=end_time)
```

I get an error of:

```
"FieldError: Join on field 'start' not permitted. Did you misspell 'time' for the lookup type?"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter in python instead using the db's mechanisms:

```
for e in Entry.objects.all():
   if i.entered.hour>= 9 and i.entered.hour < 17 :# or break down to minutes/seconds
        list.append(e)
```

but both solutions are ugly, i think.

Steve, you have to decide, what is less ugly for you:

- processsing a lot of data in a for-loop,
- or use .extra(..) and by-passing the orm-system

Comment: As of this moment this is the option I prefer. I still would like a better option.

Comment: It will be possible to filter on hour/minute in django 1.8:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#hour
Entry.objects.filter(entered__hour__gte=9, entered__hour__lte=17)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible in Django 1.8. You only can filter for exact hour match: `Entry.objects.filter(entered__hour=9)`

Comment: have you tried to filter BIG DAT? Filtering in python is much slower than in DB with indexes etc.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there's built-in support for this, but you can pass [extra where-clause](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) parameters (warning: some possibility of introducing DB-dependent behaviour here).

For example, on Postgres, something like:

```
Entry.objects.extra(where=['EXTRACT(hour from entered) >= 12 and '\
                    'EXTRACT(hour from entered) < 17'])
```

If you're using potentially unsafe input to determine the values `12` and `17`, note that you can also specify a params option to extra that will ensure proper quoting and escaping, and then use the standard sql `%s` placeholders in your where statement.

Comment: I was just about to post something along those lines. Using SQLite, `Entry.objects.extra(where=["time(entered) between '12:00' and '17:00'"])` should do the same.

Comment: Of course you can ask for time ranges without custom sql. see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Using SQLite as an example, a relatively clean and generic solution would be:

```
Entry.objects.extra(where=["time(entered) between '%s' and '%s'"],
                    params=[start_time.strftime("%H:%M"), end_time.strftime("%H:%M")])
```

Comment: This solution has small bug in it that made me struggle for half an hour: you don't need to put `%s` in quotes, so it should be `"time(entered) between %s and %s"`. At least it is how things are today, in 2015. Besides, `extra()` is deprecated now and they suggest using [RawSql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide [datetime objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) for `start_time` and `end_time`?

A quick try-out:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entered = models.DateTimeField()

>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> Entry(entered = datetime.now()).save()
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__lte = datetime.now())
[<Entry: Entry object>]
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte = datetime.now())
[]
>>> Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte = datetime.now(), entered__lte=datetime(2009,11,1,0,0))
[<Entry: Entry object>]
```

Comment: Yes, but you don’t really answer the question: it’s supposed to return every entry made between 12pm and 7pm, not matter what date.

Comment: And I do not want to filter only by the hour the time could be 12:34:54 to 14:23:06, the important thing is that the filter only consider the time and not the date.

Comment: I’m afraid that using the `extra()` modifier is the only option, then. Steven, what DB backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest filter `x<=arg` and exclude `x>=arg2`.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a solution for a similar use case – perhaps someone finds this useful:

In my case, I have Availability and Constraint models like so (simplified):

```
class Availability(...):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

class Constraint(...):
    from = models.TimeField()
    to = models.TimeField()
```

I wanted to find availabilities that don't violate any constraints.

With Postgres, this worked for me:

```
Availability.objects.extra(
    where=['NOT (start::time, "end"::time) OVERLAPS (\'{0}\'::time, \'{1}\'::time)'.format(
        from.strftime("%H:%M"), to.strftime("%H:%M")
    )]
)
```

Note how you can cast `DateTime` to `Time` (or rather `timestamp` to `time without timezone` in Postgres terms) with `::time` and then use `OVERLAPS` to compare the time ranges.

And in regards to the original question, you can also do:

```
Availability.objects.extra(
    where=['start::time BETWEEN \'{0}\'::time AND \'{1}\'::time AND
            "end"::time BETWEEN \'{0}\'::time AND \'{1}\'::time'.format(
        from.strftime("%H:%M"), to.strftime("%H:%M")
    )]
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use range to filter in between. I found this the best way to filter since SQL does filtering better than Django.

```
fromRange=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('from'),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
toRange=datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('to'),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

entry = Entry.objects.filter(entryTime__range=(fromRange,toRange))
```