# Displaying Django objects by date created

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

I built an ecommerce site for a food delivery company.  They run deliveries from 7pm-2am everynight.

I want to build a page where they can view all their orders from the beginning of time, sectioned off by each date.  But a day of deliveries on Oct 8, would include the deliveries from 7pm-11:59pm on oct 8 AND the deliveries from 12:00am to 2am on Oct 9.

I have a general idea on how to filter the objects by the "date created", but I'm not sure how to aggregate all the different days and display them in a organized manner.

I'm also using python 2.6, so i can't store each day's orders in an ordered dict.

Comment: BTW, if you need an ordered dict, you can use Django's SortedDict (https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict), but the answer below is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

Perhaps you are looking for [query range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) to select a slice of your data. Sample:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 17, 19, 00, 00, 00)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 59, 00, 00, 00)
Deliveries.objects.filter(deliveries_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

(not tested)

But, rereading your question perhaps your problem is with presentation tier, then, in your template you should 'cut' data by day. You can check if some field change in your template with [`ifchange` block tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifchanged):

```
{% for deliver in deliveries %}
    {% ifchanged deliver.deliveries_date.date %} 
            {{ deliver.deliveries_date.date }} 
    {% endifchanged %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: so would i just get one big queryset with all the orders? or should i run a for loop that gets a new queryset for each date, and then stick those querysets into a dictionary?

Comment: Can you post your model with relevant properties?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917996/how-do-i-filter-by-time-in-a-date-time-field